# Can no longer input space for string properties in Object Inspector, how to find the culprit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, delphi-ide

I use Delphi XE4 and suddenly I have found that I can no longer enter space characters (other characters are OK) into the Object Inspector for string properties such as `TButton.Caption`. I don't know since when, but it should be within the past week.

And I've been crazily busy and can't recall any significant changes/installations I have made recently that might cause this problem to the IDE.

Any advice on how to find the source of the problem? I guess some property editor expert in some installed package is causing this.

Comment: My guess is the same as yours. So disable packages until the problem goes away.

Comment: What happens when you try to enter a space? Does it completely block the input of the space, does it show a error message, does it delete the space when updating the property? What exactly happens?

Comment: @Craig when the spacebar is pressed, the IDE has no response at all, no error messages, no cursor flashing, it's just like the spacebar is not pressed at all. I'll try Rob's approach when find some time and will update back here. Thanks.

Comment: @RobKennedy It seems that I have too much packages to uninstall. Any alternatives? Is there a way to find out all packages that intercepts the string property editor, like searching for all `Class(TIDEStringEditor)` in the source code folder? Thanks.

Comment: I full-text searched for `Class(TStringProperty)`, still too much items... I'll keep trying.